# Using excel vVBA to change the value of a dropdown menu on a website

Tags: html, excel, vba, drop-down-menu

Innography is a patent search engine (https://patentscout.innography.com/).  After you enter something in the search box and hit the button, a second page opens with a list of patents.  On the left side, there are a variety of dropdown boxes where one can narrow the search (e.g., Patent Office, Filing Status, etc.).  Clicking on one of the dropdown choices immediately reloads the page with the selected filter.

I have working VBA code which puts a particular search into the box on the initial page and fires the submit button, but on the second page I can't seem to get the code to select specific items from the dropdown lists which would then apply that particular filter.  I've tried many variations on things like

ie.document.getelementbyid("source_jurisdiction").Value = "United States"

or

ie.document.getelementbyid("source_jurisdiction").Value = "8583"

Can someone help?

The code for the "Patent Office" section of the page is as follows:

```
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row cloak">
<div class="filter-panel col-md-2">
<form id="filter-form">
<a href="#" class="filter-toggle">Show Filters</a>

<div class="filter-list">

<select id="source_jurisdiction" name="source_jurisdiction" title="Filters by patent jurisdiction" data-placement="right">
<option value="">Any Patent Office</option>
<option value="8583">United States</option>
<option value="6980">Europe</option>
<option value="8779">WIPO</option>
<option value="7480">Japan</option>
<option value="6778">China</option>
<option value="-6778,-7480,-8779,-6980,-8583">Other</option>

</select>
```

Thanks!

Comment: The .Value for dropdowns corresponds to the index of the value chosen, not the value itself.

Comment: Do you really need to automate an IE instance? I suggest you simply mimic the http traffic. First, do some reverse engineering with Fiddler - but your case looks simple. Than use XmlHttpRFequest object to make the call to the server: https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I decided to take the simpler approach and just use the resulting URL from the filtered page.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I decided to take the simpler approach and just use the resulting URL from the filtered page.